# How to color JSON or XML syntaxes in SWT Text field from java

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

Currently, I'm creating a plugin which has a form in Eclipse. In that form, there is a Text filed to get user input.

```
Text txtUserInput = new Text(container, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);
fd = new FormData();
fd.top = new FormAttachment(20);
fd.left = new FormAttachment(1);
fd.right = new FormAttachment(97);
fd.width = 400;
fd.height = 100;
txtUserInput.setLayoutData(fd);
```

Here, user can enter XML, JSON or any text data as an input and, **I want to highlight the syntaxes (give colours as in IDE) when user input JSON or XML in this text box.** How can I complete this task in java?

Comment: `Text` is just a single colour. Look at `StyledText`. Syntax colouring is hard work and far too broad for a Stack Overflow answer. You could possibly look at using [Eclipse XText](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)

Comment: You have to use StyledText as Greg Sir said, or you can create a editor implementing IEditorInput and you can show color and font based upon the requirments.

Comment: You can also look at `SourceViewer` and all its associated classes such as `SourceViewerConfiguration` `PresentationReconciler` `DefaultDamagerRepairer` `RuleBasedScanner` and many others